# Proof by induction help $\sum_{i=1}^n i2^i$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification, induction

After looking at the [response](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/30732/how-can-i-evaluate-sum-n-0-inftyn1xn), the formula would be $S_n = n2^{n+2} - (n+1)2^{n+1} + 2$

How would i use induction to prove this formula? I tried setting $S_{n+1}$ but having hard time getting $S_{n+1} = S_{n} + (n+1)2^{n+1}$

Edit: Also am i doing something wrong here: $S_{n} + (n+1)2^{n+1} = n2^{n+2} + 2.$ This look weird from $S_{n+1}$

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

Let proceed by

- base case: $S_1=1\cdot 2^{3} - (2)2^{2} + 2=2$
- induction step: assume true $S_n=n2^{n+2} - (n+1)2^{n+1} + 2$ then we need to prove that

$$S_{n+1}=(n+1)2^{n+3} - (n+2)2^{n+2} + 2=\\=(n+1)2^{n+3} - (n+2)2^{n+2}-n2^{n+2} + (n+1)2^{n+1}+\overbrace{n2^{n+2} - (n+1)2^{n+1} + 2}^{S_n}\\\stackrel{?}=(n+1)2^{n+1}+S_n$$

that is

$$(n+1)2^{n+3} - (n+2)2^{n+2}-n2^{n+2} =0$$